# In VB6 why does Event processing stop in sleep loop?

Tags: events, vb6

I have a VB6 ActiveX EXE that has event handlers for an OCX control it uses.  In the ActiveX's Terminate function I need to be sure that all events have finished processing before allowing terminate to complete. In the Terminate function I've added the following code at the start:

```
While EventsInProgressFlags <> 0
    DoEvents
    Sleep(200)
WEnd
```

The EventsInProgressFlags is a Integer that I use to set which events are in progress.  However what I observe is that when this loop runs the events in progress never complete.  From adding many log messages to the events and the terminate routine I can see that the event processing is in progress when the Terminate function is called but even though I'm calling DoEvents, these in progress events do not execute while the Terminate function is active.  If I force the Terminate function to exit the loop then the event processing continues from where it left off but of course has errors because Terminate had destroyed the components used by the events.

Is there a way in my sleep loop to allow the in progress event code to finish execution?

================UPDATE 11-20-2018===================

After some online research I believe I better understand the why but don't yet have a solution.

After reading [Multithreading in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109931/multithreading-in-visual-basic-6-0) I understand that VB6 is single threaded so yes my OCX event processing and Terminate function are both in the same thread.  So this is why putting the Terminate function to sleep didn't work.  Since they are both in the same VB6 thread I also put the event processing to sleep.   I wondered how my ActiveX Terminate function was being called in the middle of my event processing code.  My theory is that since my event processing does system calls that VB6 when a system call is made, in addition to doing the system call it also calls DoEvents to service the Windows Event Queue.  This is done to make the UI more responsive.  Calling DoEvents then processes the incoming Windows event for the ActiveX Terminate Call.  I would be interested if some VB6 guru can confirm my conclusion here.

So one possible solution would be if there was some way to inhibit the system from calling DoEvents while I'm processing the OCX events.  Does anyone know of a way to do that?

Another possible solution is if there was a way to return from the Terminate function so the event processing can continue but not send the response from the Terminate function to the Host until after the Event processing is complete.  This sounds less plausible though.

Comment: I've never encountered this scenario, or investigated it, but I expect what is happening is that before your terminate event has fired the event handlers for the ocx have already been unhooked.  If so, there's nothing you can do in the terminate event to allow the ocx events to run.  Best course is probably to not release (uninstantiate) the ActiveX exe (thus not causing the ocx event handlers to unhook and the terminate event to fire) within the main app until all of the anticipated ocx events have completed.

Comment: `DoEvents` calls API's `Sleep(0)`. *The Sleep function suspends the execution of the current thread for the specified interval.* MSDN.

Comment: @MarkL Your conclusion doesn't align with my observations.   It's the ActiveX EXE's API Terminate command that is responsible for the destruction of the form so my sleep wait loop is holding off any destruction of the associated form and ActiveX EXE COM object.  I also know (from log messages) that the events that are in progress are already executing at the time the Terminate command comes in from the Host.   The Host is not under my control so I can't change when Terminate call occurs.  My only option I can see is once terminate is called to delay it until other events are complete.

Comment: But it appears that the sleep loop is not releasing the execution thread to allow the event processing that was already in progress to complete.  I'd be interested to understand the threads related to processing events in vB6.  The events that are in progress are triggered by the OCX control which then generates some software events. I can see from logs that the OCX hardware event and the associated software events have started when ActiveX EXE

Comment: Terminate is called but all execution of event processing halts until I return from the Terminate function.  In VB6 does Sleep (from kernel32) not release the current thread from execution and is event processing from OCX executing in different thread or same thread as the ActiveX EXE main event processing loop?

Comment: `DoEvents` calls `Sleep(0)`. Then you call it again with a 200ms to not do anything. Read the Docs on Sleep. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep

Comment: DoEvents will allow any pending execution paths on the same thread to run. During the .2 seconds the sleep is called, those other execution paths on that thread will not run. If you remove the sleep, you'll be allowing maximum execution to those other execution paths on that thread, but you'll likely peg the cpu within the loop, thus starving other processes of cpu cycles. Would be better to not use a spinning loop like this, but it sounds like you don't have a choice. Try reducing the sleep period to 10ms, this allows the same thread to run more often yet will starve the other processes less.

Comment: @MarkL "DoEvents will allow any pending execution paths on the same thread to run."
I don't think this is a correct statement.  I believe the correct statement is
"DoEvents will allow any pending execution paths on different threads to run."
As stated DoEvents just does a Sleep(0).  So it gives up the remaining time slice of the running thread and puts that thread back in the ready to run queue.  Whereas the Sleep(200) also gives up execution of the running thread but delays putting the thread in the run queue for 200 mSecs.

Comment: My first attempt at delaying return from Terminate function was just a loop with Sleep(200) and as noted adding the DoEvent was redundant. Since the Sleep(200) was already giving up the CPU for much longer than just one time-slice.

Comment: I question why did the event processing halt when Terminate was called and why didn't event processing continue when Terminate was put to sleep?  The only explanation I can think of is that the event processing is occurring in the same thread as the Terminate function and that the call to the ActiveX EXE Terminate function is actually interrupting event processing but still executing in the same thread.  This seems to align with the observed behavior.  If this is correct the question is:  Is there a way to mask the main event processing of ActiveX commands while events are being processed?

Comment: It does not JUST call sleep(0). It first suspends the sub/function. It then processes the message queue. Once your program has dealt with all pending messages it calls `sleep(0)` so other programs can process theirs. Its traditional use is in Word/Excel to send it keystrokes and allow Word to process them before your sub kept running. Remember VB6 hosts the VBA language like Word/Excel. It was designed for Excel.

Comment: VB6 is single threaded. Also using COM EXE programed asynch can multitask by process but not by thread.

Answer (score 0):

So once I understood that VB6 is single threaded I went back into the debugger and confirmed that when the Terminate function executes the VB6 stack shows that the OCX event processing is further up on the stack waiting until the Terminate function returns.  Clearly the event processing that I want to complete (before Terminate exits), is running in the same thread.  Terminate was "called by VB6" effectively interrupting the event processing and that means the only way to complete the event processing is to return from the Terminate command.  But returning from Terminate signals the Host (of the ActiveX EXE) that the ActiveX object is terminated when really it isn't.  The result is errors in the OCX event processing after Terminate function returns.

What I wanted was a way to inhibit the processing of incoming commands to the ActiveX EXE.  This would hold off execution of the Terminate function while the event processing is in progress. I was unable to find any way to do that.

So the less than elegant solution I came up with was to add a global HasTerminated
Boolean flag that is set by the Terminate subroutine. Then the error
handlers for the button event routines that were generating error ***#91 "Object variable or With block variable not set"*** were modified to ignore error #91 but only if the HasTerminated Boolean flag is True.  What this does is abort any event processing that causes an error but only if ActiveX has been terminated.  This was an acceptable solution in that the OCX events didn't need to complete since the component was being terminated.  They just needed to not cause error. Here's a sample error handler I added to all event processing routines.

```
M_SIGN_CAPTURE_FORM_CLEAR_CLICKED_ERR_HANDLER:
40  If HasTerminated And Err.Number = 91 Then
50      Resume 30 ' Resume at Exit Sub
60  End If

70  ErrBox "ERROR #" & Err.Number & " " & FILE__ _
        & ":m_SignCaptureForm_ClearClicked:" & Erl & Err.Description
80  Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Experiment with taking a second reference to the COM EXE. It won't exit till ref count is 0. If it's in the running object table use `GetObject`.

Comment: Not following. If you mean create new instance of the ActiveX that's not feasible nor is creating new process. The OCX event processing needs access to the components contained in the current ActiveX instance.  The ActiveX instance is created by a 3rd party. Issue is the Terminate function is called from the event processing code not directly but by VB6 itself via event queue.  The code that needs to complete is higher up on the stack in the same thread.  So no way to get to it from Terminate.  The answer is disabling cmd processing during event processing which doesn't appear possible.

Comment: Perhaps post your call stack.